# kaniko sh: sleep: not found

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried to build images on my k8s cluster using kaniko,i got this:

sh: touch: not found

sh: sleep: not found

```
container("kaniko") {
              sh "kaniko -f `pwd`/Dockerfile -c `pwd` --destination=${ORIGIN_REPO}/${REPO}:${IMAGE_TAG} "
          }
```

Comment: Why you tagged `C#`?

Comment: this  dockerfile is about netcore,hahh~

Comment: Wouldn't that be more "meaningful" to tag .net core then?

Comment: I'm wondering if you resolved your issue, and how you did it.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/master/README.md#debug-image) documentation:

"The kaniko executor image is based off of scratch and doesn't contain a shell. We provide gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug, a debug image which consists of the kaniko executor image along with a busybox shell to enter.

You can launch the debug image with a shell entrypoint:

`docker run -it --entrypoint=/busybox/sh gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to specify a shell also,

so for example:

```
container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh')
```